# Can't identify old Chinese(?) and American radio/telephone

Tags: electronics, transceiver, military-surplus

I have searched image banks and Googled period radios, but I can not identify these old units. I picked them up overseas in SE Asia and I got them as projects to teach myself enough to challenge the Advanced Amateur Operators certification exam. I find hands on better than books all the time so these got my interest.

I have some model numbers like the American set, but it is a control set...without frequency tuner? There are some sort of numbers on one of the Asian character sets, but I cannot translate.

They are without battery packs or antenna so I need to replace/bodge alternates. I am not licensed to transmit in my current country but would like to revive these units. I am no expert and will learn by doing.

The hand sets are:

- Telephone Set TA-1/PT...Jeep handset?
- NHA MAY THONG TIN M3 DT-97 (No: 01-03-03-010)...Vietnamese telephone?

[image: 2x chinese and 1x american military radios]

[image: Control, Radio SETC-2329A/GRA-39]

[image: Id plate for above set]

[image: No ID plate Korean/Chinese/Vietnamese radio?]

[image: Seems to be a ??:72-05031 ?-251A radio]

Comment: Hi Joe, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Would you please [edit](https://ham.stackexchange.com/posts/16746/edit) your post and add detailed photos of each item, especially of identification plates and such?

Comment: I attempted translation of the Chinese characters into English using two Android apps which work from smartphone camera images. Very limited success. Did you contact local VFW or Asian community organizations?

Comment: Perhaps someone at https://chinese.stackexchange.com could help. You might ask in their [chat room](https://chinese.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The characters *are* Chinese, but it could still be a Vietnamese radio or perhaps Japanese or Korean.  Japan uses some of the same characters, and other Asian countries historically used Chinese characters even though they have their own writing systems now.

Comment: *NHA MAY THONG TIN* sure looks like modern Vietnamese one-syllable words to me. Also, Googling for *vietnamese letters*, there is an older Vietnamese character set that looks a lot like Chinese. I doubt if it's Korean, because there are no small circles in the letters that is characteristic of Korean writing. Japanese? I can't say. "SE Asia" sounds to me like these were used in the war in Vietnam, so one might think these Chinese-looking characters are Vietnamese. **Edit:** following @workerjoe's link in his profile, it seems like he knows for certain that these *are* Chinese.

Comment: All these items were acquired from Vietnam but there is no provenance to speak of.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some information on GRA-39 Radio Set Control, TA-1 Telephone Set and Chinese 251A Radio Set.

http://www.prc68.com/I/GRA39.shtml

https://www.prc68.com/I/TA1.shtml

http://chinesemilitaryradio.blogspot.com/2008/10/silicon-two-watt-short-wave-transceiver.html

Comment: Thanks for the references. The american site looks like a great reference to try and piece together a working version.

The Vietnamese reference seems on topic but a different unit design. I will look at the site for other links.

The Vietnamese hand set looks like it may be a field telephone as the box has a hole where it may take a crank for some internal dynamo.

Comment: Anytime, Joe! I'm sure more information and schematics can be accessed. Have fun! 73, Nandu.

Comment: Hi Joe, I've now furnished the correct link for information on the Chinese set.

Answer (score 0):

It's Chinese on last two photos. The tag information on the last photo is: Transistor 2W HF Radio Mode 2. Serial No: 72-05031, Comm 251A. It's a very widely used HF radio in CPLA in 70s.

Here're some specs I found online. 
Frequency: Band 1: 1.7 - 3.2 MHz 
           Band 2: 3.2 - 6.0 MHz
RF output Power: AM phone >= 1W 
                 CW       >= 2W
Power consumption: RX 24V/40-45mA
                   TX 24V/550mA
Sensitivity: AM <10uV
             CW <5uV
Range:   1.5m antenna:  10km(day)/5km(night)
         15m  antenna:  20km(day)
         44m dipole antenna 90km(day)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for joining and contributing, Bo. Please share with us the references where you found this useful information.

Comment: Thanks Brian I can puzzle out some voltages at least. I think I have found the unit names from a collector:


Silicon Two Watt Shortwave Tranceiver
[link](http://chinesemilitaryradio.blogspot.com/2008/10/silicon-two-watt-short-wave-transceiver.html).

884 VHF FM Backpack
[link](http://chinesemilitaryradio.blogspot.com/2007/11/884-vhf-fm-backpack.html).


Now I need to source some spare parts and schematics maybe. I will have a look around the link you provided with the manual.

Answer (score 0):

@Brian K1LI. It's from Chinese BBS. Here's one with manual.

http://www.360doc.com/content/13/0304/21/8482771_269312580.shtml

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!

Comment: Seems you are able to read the Chinese characters. I tried, but failed, to read them with an Android app. Is there anything special about these characters that makes them difficult for an app to read ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: @Brian K1LI, I'm originally from China so I can read Chinese. For computer, translate any language from image/photo is more difficult than from text directly. The extra step is OCR. And it's much more difficult for Chinese because there're more than 10,000 Chinese characters comparing to 26 letters in English :)

Answer (score 0):

GRA-39 Radio Set Control, 
TA-1 Telephone Set, 
Silicon 2W Short Wave Transceiver, 
884 VHF FM Backpack (also known as a Comm 251A),

I think 'NHA MAY THONG TIN M3' refers to an Information Tech manufacturer named 'M3' and DT-97 is a model number, but I haven't found documentation on it yet.

Joe
73 V01WJG